# How to use prefix to reference to a folder in a S3 bucket in CDK?

Tags: typescript, amazon-s3, aws-cdk

I am trying to have a metric using CDK that tracks number of http uploads to a folder in a s3 bucket. The folder is a nested folder.  It is named "folderB" and resides in "folderA".  In other words, it has "folderA/folderB/" structure.

In CDK, using [BucketMetrics](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_s3.BucketMetrics.html), the prefix should be "folderA/folderB".  I keep running into an error says the XML is malformed.  I understand in S3, everything is an object and flat; how do I use `prefix` to present the nested folder in the s3 bucket?

Comment: Please add your code and the exact error.

Comment: Its unclear why you are getting an XML exception.  Can you share a sample of your CDK code?  It is hard to diagnose your issue without code.  It may have nothing to do with the prefix.